# Interpolating sf LINESTRING to another pre-defined grid

Tags: r, line, interpolation, sf

I have a set of sf lines, which on an irregular grid, in other words, they have random coordinates.
Is there any way to interpolate LINESTRING coordinates to a regualr grid for example as defined below:

```
> class(lines)
[1] "sf"         "data.frame"

> lines
Geometry set for 9 features 
geometry type:  LINESTRING
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 160.6388 ymin: -17.22663 xmax: 277.5178 ymax: 12.53342
CRS:            +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
First 5 geometries:
LINESTRING (160.6388 -8.756245, 160.7918 -8.826...
LINESTRING (160.6388 -8.756245, 160.7918 -8.826...
LINESTRING (187.4896 2.427888, 187.5281 2.43538...
LINESTRING (160.6388 -8.756245, 160.7918 -8.826...
LINESTRING (160.6388 -8.756245, 160.7918 -8.826...

#Pre-defined regular grid 
desired_lon <- seq(0,360,0.5)
desired_lat <- seq(90,-90,-0.5)
```

I have tried `interp()` from interp package in R  didn't work well. since the input should be points, Lines IDs and Lines vertices sort ID will be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this solution and it has been tested to interpolate to a finer grid.

```
#A function to interpolate  lines to another coordination

lines_interpolation<-function(2Darray,raw_line){

 require(sf)


 DIMNAMES<-dimnames(2Darray)

 lon<-as.numeric(DIMNAMES[[1]])
 lat<-as.numeric(DIMNAMES[[2]])


 interpolated_LINE<-raw_line


 raw_line_crs<-st_coordinates(raw_line)

 interpolated_crs<-raw_line_crs

 for (k in 1:nrow(raw_line_crs)) {
    
  lon_div<-abs(lon-raw_line_crs[k,1])
    
  near_lon_index<-which(lon_div ==min(lon_div))
    
  interpolated_crs[k,1]<-lon[near_lon_index]
    
  lat_div<-abs(lat-raw_line_crs[k,2])
    
  near_lat_index<-which(lat_div ==min(lat_div))
    
  interpolated_crs[k,2]<-lat[near_lat_index]
    
 }

 interpolated_line_crs<-unique(interpolated_crs)
  
 interpolated_line<-st_linestring(x = as.matrix(interpolated_line_crs),
  dim= "XYM")
  

 interpolated_line<-st_as_sf(interpolated_line)  
 #Convert data frame to sf object and assign CRS

 st_crs(interpolated_line)<-"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84" 


 return(interpolated_line)
}
```